# "message": "Uncaught TypeError: x.addEventListenern is not a function",?

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript and HTML.Trying to practice on DOM. I am stuck with this problem, and this code is not executing. Giving me error thatx.addEventListenern is not a function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  

      var counter = 0;

        var x = document.getElementById("button");

        x.addEventListenern("click",button1,false);        
            function button1 ()
        {
        counter ++;

        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Counter =" + counter;
        }


        
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>

          <title>Counter</title>

          <script type="text/javascript" src= "Counter.js"></script>

         <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="Counter.css"/>
       </head>
      <body>
      <div>

         <button id ="button">Increment</button><br/>

     </div>
       <p id = "counter"></p>


       <p id = "demo"></p>
    
      </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: addEventListenern should be addEventListener ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>    
        <title>Counter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="Counter.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id ="button">Increment</button><br/>    
        </div>
        <p id = "counter"></p>
        <p id = "demo"></p>
        <script>
            var counter = 0;
            var x = document.getElementById("button");
            x.addEventListener("click",button1,false);
            function button1 ()
            {
                counter ++;  
                document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML ="Counter ="+counter;
            }
        </script>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Check the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jqg6nb81/)

Comment: You shouldn't put the script after `</html>`

Comment: @Bálint - Thanks. Fixed

Comment: @ Shakti - Thanks

Comment: @YeashinRabbi - If this answers your question, please mark it as answer